# White Space on the right of page

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone I've got this classic problem of a large margin of white space being generated on the right side of my site. Before anyone asks yes I have tried

```
html, 
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

I've had zero luck. I've tried a lot of things and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. I am very new to code so there's a solid chance I'm overlooking something or did something insanely stupid. At 1080p it's fine but on higher resolution displays it becomes an issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVntd.jpg) Here's a link to my work.   https://github.com/NdigiG/Portfolio Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Hi Ndigi. Have you tried using the debugging tools in your browser to inspect for roguely positioned elements on your page that might be pushing out that right margin? The code you linked to has a fixed width and a lot of absolutely positioned elements -- it should be pretty obvious if an element is out of place using the inspection tools of any browser's in-built debugging tools. It may also help to know if this is happening in some or all browsers.

Comment: Welcome Ndigi :) ... for better assistance you can use code snippet (https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) while you post/edit to demonstrates the problem

Comment: hi @Ndigi please update your repo, images are missing, i cant get what you are doing.

Comment: @Cory So far I've only tried chrome but I checked the developer tools and from what I can gather the body is creating a margin but I have no idea why. I've tried setting the margin and padding to 0 for both the body and html and nothing has worked.

Comment: @vanduc1102 I've updated the repo with my assets. Sorry I forgot to put those up earlier...

Comment: Was this fixed? I just downloaded your repo and there isn't any white space on the right side of your page. In fact, the "About", "Work" and "Contact" are so far to the right that they are off the page.

Comment: @aCarella I'm still seeing white space on my end...

Comment: That's weird. I have your page opened on my mac in Safai and Chrome.

If you update your original post with a screenshot and arrow pointing to where you are talking about, I can try to troubleshoot.

Comment: @aCarella I've updated the post with a picture. I should've specified this sooner but the problem only appears upwards of 1080p.

Comment: Can you try my solution: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/adevduck-monosnap/2018-08-31-10-13-07.jpg,  https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/adevduck-monosnap/2018-08-31-10-14-02.jpg , your code is not responsive, that why you have an issue on big screen, I think center the content on bigscreen is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are fixing your width in the body, header, and footer to 1920px, that is why on screens larger than 1920px, you are going to see white space.

If you want it to be responsive (dynamic) filling the whole screen, you would need to find all `width: 1920px;` and convert them to `width: 100%;`. These are in `uhh.css` file.